# Page Border problem in memoir

Tags: memoir, border

I'm working on a Gospel book for liturgical use (~500 pages) based on the memoir document class (it can be processed with `pdfLaTeX` and the minimal example below, although I'm actually using `XeLaTeX`), and I've figured out how to produce a page border via the picture environment. The minimum example uses a couple of common glyphs to demonstrate the problem: I can't control the border, once the command for it has been issued. I'd like some pages to be truly blank and borderless.

Moving `\pageborder` to a point later in the document will allow prior pages to be borderless. But after that command is issued, how to produce borderless page? It seems that something would have to be added or modified to the `\pagestyle` command (or deeper still) to introduce a really blank page. But how? Or should I use another way to produce the border and not the picture environment?

I've seen what can be done with `pgfornaments`, etc. -- but I shy away from it since it looks too complicated to me! Maybe someone will convince me otherwise, but I'm skeptical. :-)

I'm using MacTeX 2022 installed on OS10.14.6.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[11pt,draft]{memoir}
\settypeblocksize{8in}{5in}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}
\setulmargins{1.5in}{*}{.5}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand\pageborder{
\fancyput{% 
\setlength{\unitlength}{12bp}% 
\begin{picture}(0,44)%
\fontsize{12bp}{12bp}\selectfont\color{red}%
\put(-2,3){+}%  upper left corner
\put(-1,3){ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo}% top row
\put(40,3){+}%  upper right corner
\put(-2,-57){+}%  bottom left corner
\put(-1,-57){ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo}%  botom row
\put(40,-57){+} %  bottom right corner          
\end{picture}}{} 
}

\setsecnumdepth{chapter}

\pagestyle{ruled}
\makeevenhead{ruled}{\thepage}{\MakeLowercase{\scshape The Real Story}}{}
\makeoddhead{ruled}{}{\MakeLowercase{\scshape Raw and Unfiltered}}{\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{ruled}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{ruled}{}{}{}

\title{The Beginning of My Troublesâ€¦}
\author{Yours Truly}

\begin{document}
\maketitle\pageborder
\lipsum[1-9]
\chapter{I tried everything}
\lipsum[10-20]
\chapter{Same old same old}
\lipsum[21-24]\pagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[41]
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[44]




\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for adding a minimal document. You can display code by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` icon. Inline code can be marked with backticks. Also, questions typically shouldn't have 'thanks' or your name.

Comment: I would probably add it via the page styles and by using the new background hooks (requires a modern latex installation).

Comment: It seems to be doable using the `\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{picture commands}` see `lthooks` and `ltshipout-doc` for details (you can look them up via texdoc.net). We use `\AddToHookNext` to only add the decoration of the page that is currently given the relevant page style. As soon as a different page style is in effect when the page is shipped out, the decoration is not added.

Comment: you should call `\pageborder` from a page head in a page style, not from the document body, then use `\pagetyle` or `\thispagestyle` to switch between border or no border styles

Comment: I wouldn't use the fancyput command. It changes an internal LaTeX  command (`\@outputpage`) but as the package hasn't been updated for over 10 years it doesn't include the change made by latex here. Use the options provided by  memoir to include your border into the pagestyles.

Comment: Brilliant, Brilliant and Brilliant! I knew you would supply the need! I intuited using the \pagestyle as the switch, but didn't know how to achieve it. Now it works just fine.

My gratitude to Lars for his assistance, to Ulrike for warning about fancybox (I have duly repented --- "quoth the raven: Nevermore!") and for David, providing all the details, even editing the positions for the \put command.

All of you are perpetually enrolled in our prayers here at the monastery. That's the way I know I can repay your kindness!

United in adoration of Jesus,

fr. michael gilmary, mma

Comment: Lars, I've found that I'd rather use a \put coordinate not relative to the position of the header box of the \pagestyle but to the edge of the page absolutely, (if I can) yet invoked when a certain pagestyle is issued. (I'd like the box to be centered on the page rather than guess depending on point size, etc.)
Is there a way to use \AddToHookNext for this?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I added the border to the `ruled` and `plain` page styles. but not to `empty` so you can enable/disable borders using `\(this)pagestyle`

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[11pt,draft]{memoir}
\settypeblocksize{8in}{5in}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}
\setulmargins{1.5in}{*}{.5}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand\pageborder{%<<< you need this
%\fancyput{% 
\setlength{\unitlength}{12bp}% 
\begin{picture}(0,0)% 0,0
\fontsize{12bp}{12bp}\selectfont\color{red}%
\put(-4,3){+}%  upper left corner
\put(-3,3){ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo}% top row
\put(38,3){+}%  upper right corner
\put(-4,-57){+}%  bottom left corner
\put(-3,-57){ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo}%  botom row
\put(38,-57){+} %  bottom right corner          
\end{picture}%<<< you need this 
}

\setsecnumdepth{chapter}

\pagestyle{ruled}
\makeevenhead{ruled}{\pageborder\thepage}{\MakeLowercase{\scshape The Real Story}}{}
\makeoddhead{ruled}{\pageborder}{\MakeLowercase{\scshape Raw and Unfiltered}}{\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{ruled}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{ruled}{}{}{}
\makeevenhead{plain}{\pageborder}{}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{\pageborder}{}{}


\title{The Beginning of My Troublesâ€¦}
\author{Yours Truly}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-9]
\chapter{I tried everything}
\lipsum[10-20]
\chapter{Same old same old}
\lipsum[21-24]\pagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[41]
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[44]




\end{document}
```